# Auth0 react native iOS token response

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-native, auth0

I have set up a custom login form with Auth0.

I am able to log in with the following:

```
export default function auth0Login(webAuth, {email, password}) {
  return webAuth.auth
  .passwordRealm({
    username: email,
    password,
    realm: AUTH0_DB_CONNECTION,
    scope: 'openid profile email'
  });
}
```

and can authenticate with

```
export default function getWebAuth() {
  return new Auth0({
    domain: AUTH0_DOMAIN,
    clientId: AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    redirectUri: 'pingo33://pingo33.auth0.com/ios/pingo33/signin',
    scope: 'openid profile'
  });
}
```

How can I redirect to `'/singin'` after authentication? I have in my allowed callbacks

```
pingo33://pingo33.auth0.com/ios/pingo33/signin
```

I want to be able to grab the token passed in the response url to signin

Thank you